# MySQL - Combinatory constraint for two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

This is not the typical constraint on two columns.

Here is a table with foreign keys ref1, ref2:

```
connection_id | ref1_id  | ref2_id
1             |     1    |    2
```

I would like to allow:

```
connection_id | ref1_id  | ref2_id
1             |     1    |    2
2             |     1    |    3
```

but disallow these two:

```
(typical unique key on ref1,ref2 - this I know how to do)
connection_id | ref1_id  | ref2_id
1             |     1    |    2
2             |     1    |    2
```

but also!!:

```
(this is the problem)
connection_id | ref1_id  | ref2_id
1             |     1    |    2
2             |     2    |    1
```

because I would like only one ref1-ref2 pair - for me the pair (ref1,ref2) or (1,2) is the same as (2,1) and should be disallowed by a unique key constraint. Is there a way to do that in MySQL?

I am sure that it was answered already, but when searching I always hit the typical unique constraint on two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1: Considering your datatype for ref1_id and ref2_id are within the limits of a integer data type and there exists an integer data type which can fit `sizeof ref1_id + sizeof ref2_id` in mysql.

Add a new calculated column to your table with the type which can fit it and calculate it as
`min(ref1_id, ref2_id) << (size_in_bits_of_the_biggest_of_the_types_of_ref1_id_and_ref2_id) + max(ref1_id, ref2_id)` within a trigger before insert or update - this way the whole row will be rejected due to unique constraint violation.

Variant 2: Use this if variant 1 is not applicable as it will be slower.

Add a new calculated column to your table as varchar long enough to fit the text representations of `concat(max(ref1_id), ' ', max(ref2_id))` - fake code, use max posible value here and calculate it as
`CONCAT(min(ref1_id, ref2_id), ' ', max(ref1_id, ref2_id))` within a trigger before insert or update - this way the whole row will be rejected due to unique constraint violation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use canonical order of data in `INSERT`/`UPDATE` queries (for example ref1_id always less than ref2_id) or custom check duplicates with `ON BEFORE INSERT`/`UPDATE` trigger.

This task can not be solved using constraints only.

Edit:
There is no way to abort `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement with trigger, so the whole solution is even worse :-)

```
DELIMITER ###

CREATE TRIGGER `after_up` 
  AFTER UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE collision INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT 1  
    INTO collision
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE ref1_id = NEW.ref2_id AND ref2_id = NEW.ref1_id;
  IF collision
  THEN -- reverting update
    UPDATE my_table SET ref2_id = OLD.ref2_id, ref1_id = OLD.ref1_id WHERE connection_id = OLD.connection_id;
  END IF;
END

###

CREATE TRIGGER `after_in` 
  AFTER INSERT ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE collision INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT 1  
    INTO collision
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE ref1_id = NEW.ref2_id AND ref2_id = NEW.ref1_id;
  IF collision
  THEN -- deleting new row
    DELETE FROM my_table WHERE connection_id = NEW.connection_id;
  END IF;
END

###

delimiter ;
```

Edit 2: Just found hack to abort query in trigger (`DROP TABLE nonexistent_table_name`)

```
DELIMITER ###

CREATE TRIGGER `before_up` 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE collision INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT 1  
    INTO collision
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE ref1_id = NEW.ref2_id AND ref2_id = NEW.ref1_id;
  IF collision
  THEN -- throwing error
     DROP TABLE __error_duplicate_detected;        
  END IF;
END

###

CREATE TRIGGER `before_in` 
  BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE collision INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT 1  
    INTO collision
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE ref1_id = NEW.ref2_id AND ref2_id = NEW.ref1_id;
  IF collision
  THEN -- throwing error
     DROP TABLE __error_duplicate_detected;        
  END IF;
END

###

delimiter ;
```

Comment: +1 For the ideas, unfortunately forced order is not applicable in my case, and I'd like to avoid as much as possible to use triggers if I can, maybe I'll have to do it as a last resort.

Comment: Do you have an example of such trigger that should throw an error?

Comment: If I understand the logic correctly, these triggers silently ignore the rows that would violate the constraint, instead of refusing to perform the insert/update?

Comment: first edition triggers will silently ignore, second edition will throw readable error `ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table ‘__error_duplicate_detected’`

Comment: Yep, I just saw your edit. The other way to implement the trigger would be to always insert the "mirrorred" row as well; that would fire the normal duplicate/unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE pair CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE pair
      ( pair_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      , aaa INTEGER NOT NULL
      , bbb INTEGER NOT NULL
      , CONSTRAINT aaa_bbb UNIQUE (aaa, bbb)
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX aaaXXXbbb ON pair ( LEAST(aaa, bbb), GREATEST(aaa, bbb) )
        ;
INSERT INTO pair(aaa,bbb) VALUES(1,1), (1,2),(2,2);

INSERT INTO pair(aaa,bbb) VALUES(2,1);

SELECT * FROM pair;
```

Result:

```
INSERT 0 3
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "aaaxxxbbb"
DETAIL:  Key ((LEAST(aaa, bbb)), (GREATEST(aaa, bbb)))=(1, 2) already exists.
 pair_id | aaa | bbb 
---------+-----+-----
       1 |   1 |   1
       2 |   1 |   2
       3 |   2 |   2
(3 rows)
```

I don't know if mysql allows and enforces constraints or indexes on expressions. Postgres does allow indexes on expressions, but unfortunately no constraints on expressions. If indexes are not possible the obvious tie-breaking constraint would of course be `aaa >= bbb`, like in @vearutob 's answer.

BTW: in this model, the constraint on (aaa,bbb) is redundant, because the condition is already covered by the index. (I would like to have them swapped: the constraint on {least,greatest} and the index on the bare columns, but postgres does not seem to allow this yet)

Comment: `SERIAL` is typical for postgresql (an extension), in mysql you write that as `int auto_increment`

Comment: The surrogate key is totally irrelevant, even redundant, and should be omitted. I just posted the code that I used for testing, which closely resembles the *intention* of the OP.

Comment: +1 because this seems to be a good idea for postgres, but on MySQL, I have the error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'aaa, bbb), GREATEST(aaa, bbb) )' at line 1`

Comment: That is why a added the disclaimer below the fragment. Apart from the platform or implementation, the problem itself is universal (BTW the OQ was also tagged `sql`.)

Comment: In MySQL you can't add unique index or unique constraint on expression only on column(s). Also you can't add virtual/calculated column to add unique index on it (As you can do it for example in Oracle). So only way I agree with @vearutop is to add trigger to check ref1 and ref2 on insert and update.

Comment: This kind of solution would work in MariaDB (a MySQL fork) that has virtual columns.

Comment: See the similar problem: [Unique combination key MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/unique-combination-key-mysql)